# Unable to install wine32, but I can install win64

Tags: apt, software-installation, xubuntu, wine, 20.10

I have a problem installing wine32, I really try too many thing and I am out of ideas some give me some help please.

```
**name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$** sudo apt-get install wine32

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:

  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 : Depende: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.5.9) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

**name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$** sudo apt install libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:

 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 : Depende: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.5.9) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.


**name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$** uname -a

Linux name-desktop 5.8.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:18:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And if I try to install ***libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.5.9)*** all my xfce pkgs unnistall, look

```
**name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$** sudo apt install libsqlite3-0:i386

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.

  accountsservice acl appmenu-gtk-module-common appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-registrar apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data aptitude-common atril-common
  avahi-utils bolt bubblewrap cabextract cheese-common colord-data cups-ipp-utils cups-pk-helper cups-server-common dc distro-info-data
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base docbook-xml docbook-xsl enchant-2 engrampa-common finalrd fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-lyx fonts-mathjax fonts-wine
  gdbserver gimp-data gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-unity-5.0 git-man gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-software-common gnome-themes-standard gnu-smalltalk
  gnu-smalltalk-common gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common gpgsm gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 icoutils intel-media-va-driver:i386 ipp-usb java-common javascript-common jq kwayland-data
  kwayland-integration launchpad-getkeys ledit libaa1:i386 libabw-0.1-1 libamd2 libaom0:i386 libappmenu-gtk2-parser0 libasn1-8-heimdal
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec58:i386
  libavutil56:i386 libbabeltrace1 libbabl-0.1-0 libbamf3-2 libblkid-dev libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0
  libboost-locale1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0 libburn4 libc-ares2 libc6-dbg libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-perl
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcamd2 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libccolamd2 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcdr-0.1-1
  libcholmod3 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libclutter-1.0-common libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20
  libcogl20 libcolamd2 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcupsimage2 libcwidget4 libdatrie-dev libdav1d4:i386 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libdbusmenu-gtk4 libde265-0 libdee-1.0-4 libdv4:i386 libdw1:i386 libe-book-0.1-1 libenchant-2-2 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 liberror-perl
  libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-7 libexif12 libexif12:i386 libexiv2-27 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libexttextcat-2.0-0
  libextutils-depends-perl libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libffi-dev libfindlib-ocaml libfindlib-ocaml-dev libfluidsynth2
  libfontembed1 libfreehand-0.1-1 libfreexl1 libfribidi-dev libgadu3 libgbm1:i386 libgcab-1.0-0 libgd3:i386 libgdata-common libgdbm-compat4:i386
  libgdbm6:i386 libgdiplus libgee-0.8-2 libgegl-common libgeos-3.8.1 libgeos-c1v5 libgexiv2-2 libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl
  libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgnome-games-support-common libgnustep-base1.27 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1:i386 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-l10n libgraphite2-dev libgsm1:i386 libgspell-1-common libgst7 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-common libgtk2-perl libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell0 libgtop-2.0-11
  libgtop2-common libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libgusb2 libgxps2 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheif1
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libhpmud0 libhx509-5-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libhyphen0 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3
  libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386 libimagequant0 libinstpatch-1.0-2 libisofs6 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjq1 libjs-jquery libjs-mathjax
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libjs-xmlextras libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common libjte2 libkate1 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin
  libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkpathsea6 libksba8
  liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-common liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml-data liblouisutdml9 libltc11 libmalcontent-0-0 libmbim-glib4
  libmbim-proxy libmeanwhile1 libmessaging-menu0 libmetis5 libmhash2 libminiupnpc17 libminizip1 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmm-glib0 libmms0 libmodplug1
  libmono-2.0-1 libmono-2.0-dev libmono-accessibility4.0-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil
  libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil libmono-management4.0-cil
  libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil libmono-messaging4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil libmono-oracle4.0-cil libmono-parallel4.0-cil libmono-peapi4.0a-cil
  libmono-profiler libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil libmono-relaxng4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-simd4.0-cil libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil
  libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil libmono-system-data4.0-cil libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil
  libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil libmono-system-json4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil
  libmono-system-management4.0-cil libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil libmono-system-net4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil
  libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil libmono-system-windows4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-tasklets4.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil
  libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil libmonoboehm-2.0-1 libmonosgen-2.0-1 libmonosgen-2.0-dev libmount-dev libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpcdec6 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmpg123-0:i386 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmspack0 libmspub-0.1-1 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libmypaint-1.5-1 libmypaint-common libmysqlclient21 libmysqlclient21:i386 libmythes-1.name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$2-0 libnatpmp1 libncurses-dev libndp0 libneon27-gnutls
  libnfs13 libnghttp2-14 libnghttp2-14:i386 libnm0 libnma-common libnspr4 libnspr4:i386 libnuma1:i386 libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core2.6.3-cil libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libodfgen-0.1-1 libofa0 libonig5 liboobs-1-5
  libopenjp2-7:i386 libopenni2-0 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 liborcus-0.15-0 liborcus-parser-0.15-0 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpango-perl libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpcap0.8:i386 libpci3:i386 libpcre16-3 libpcre2-dev
  libpcre2-posix2 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libperl5.30:i386 libprotobuf-c1 libpsl5:i386 libpulsedsp libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy
  libqpdf28 libqqwing2v5 libqrencode4 libraw1394-11:i386 libraw19 librevenge-0.0-0 libroken18-heimdal libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1 librtmp1:i386
  librttopo1 libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsbc1 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1-dev libsepol1-dev libshine3:i386 libshout3 libshout3:i386
  libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libslang2:i386 libsmbios-c2 libsnappy1v5:i386 libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libsnmp35:i386 libsoundtouch1 libsoxr0:i386 libspandsp2
  libspectre1 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libssh-4:i386 libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstemmer0d libsuitesparseconfig5 libswresample3:i386
  libsynctex2 libtag1v5 libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtagc0 libtalloc2 libtcl8.6 libteamdctl0 libtevent0 libthai-dev
  libtheora0:i386 libtk8.6 libtumbler-1-0 libtwolame0:i386 libumfpack5 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9
  libunwind8:i386 libv4l-0 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0 libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386
  libvisio-0.1-1 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libvpx6:i386 libvte-2.91-common libwavpack1:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libwbclient0 libwebpmux3:i386 libwebrtc-audio-processing1
  libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwildmidi2 libwind0-heimdal libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwnck-3-common libwoff1 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3
  libwps-0.4-4 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libx264-160:i386 libx265-192:i386 libxapian30 libxatracker2 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-res0 libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml2-utils
  libxmlb1 libxmlsec1 libxnvctrl0 libxpm4:i386 libxpresent1 libxslt1.1:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libyajl2 libyaml-0-2 libzbar0 libzephyr4
  libzvbi0:i386 localechooser-data lp-solve lzip lzop mate-calc-common mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mobile-broadband-provider-info
  modemmanager mono-4.0-service mono-csharp-shell mono-mcs mono-utils mono-xbuild monodoc-base mscompress node-jquery ocaml-base-nox
  ocaml-compiler-libs ocaml-findlib ocaml-interp ocaml-man ocaml-nox ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit p11-kit-modules pango1.0-tools pidgin-data
  polkit-kde-agent-1 pptp-linux proj-data pulseaudio-utils python-apt-common python-natsort-doc rtkit samba-common sbsigntool secureboot-db
  sgml-base sgml-data shimmer-themes system-tools-backends tango-icon-theme tcl8.6 thunar-data timgm6mb-soundfont tpm-udev transmission-common
  tumbler-common unar usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data user-setup va-driver-all:i386 vala-panel-appmenu-common vdpau-driver-all:i386 vim-runtime
  whoopsie-preferences x11-apps x11-session-utils xclip xdg-dbus-proxy xfdesktop4-data xinit xml-core xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yelp-xsl zenity-common

Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:

  appmenu-gtk3-module apport apport-gtk appstream apt-config-icons aptdaemon apturl apturl-common atril bamfdaemon blueman bluez-cups
  ca-certificates-java casper catfish cifs-utils colord cups cups-browsed cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers
  default-jdk default-jdk-headless default-jre default-jre-headless dirmngr engrampa exo-utils firefox foomatic-db-compressed-ppds fwupd
  fwupd-signed gcr gdb gigolo gimp gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-cheese-3.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-mines
  gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-sudoku gnome-system-tools gnupg gpg gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  gstreamer1.0-nice gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gucharmap gvfs-backends hplip hplip-data kerneloops
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libappindicator3-1 libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libatk1.0-dev
  libatrildocument3 libatrilview3 libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libcairo2-dev libcaja-extension1
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcurl3-gnutls
  libcurl4 libexo-2-0 libfarstream-0.2-5 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgarcon-gtk3-1-0 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata22 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgegl-0.4-0
  libgimp2.0 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgpgme11 libgpgmepp6 libgspell-1-2
  libgssapi3-heimdal libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk2.0-dev libgtk3-perl libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgucharmap-2-90-7
  libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libharfbuzz-dev libheimntlm0-heimdal libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 libjcat1 libkeybinder-3.0-0
  libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libldb2 libmono-cil-dev libmono-http4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil libnice10 libnma0 libnss3 libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-util2.6.3-cil libpango1.0-dev libpoppler-cpp0v5 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler102 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8
  libpython3.8-stdlib libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 libsane1 libsmbclient libsnapd-glib1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libsoup2.4-1 libsqlite3-0 libsrtp2-1 libthunarx-3-0 libtss2-esys0 libvte-2.91-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwine libwnck-3-0 libxfce4panel-2.0-4
  libxfce4ui-2-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-dev libxmlsec1-nss libyelp0 lightdm-gtk-greeter lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings lsb-release mate-calc
  menulibre minecraft-launcher mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mono-complete mono-devel mono-xsp4 mono-xsp4-base monodoc-http monodoc-manual
  mousepad mugshot network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome onboard onboard-common onboard-data
  openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless openprinting-ppds packagekit packagekit-tools parole pastebinit pavucontrol pidgin pinentry-gnome3
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text policykit-1-gnome poppler-utils printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi
  printer-driver-splix pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-blinker python3-cairo python3-certifi python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-click python3-colorama python3-cryptography
  python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dateutil python3-dbus python3-debconf python3-debian python3-defer python3-distro python3-distro-info
  python3-distupgrade python3-distutils python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2 python3-idna python3-jeepney python3-jwt python3-keyring
  python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-lazr.uri python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-oauthlib python3-olefile python3-pexpect
  python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-psutil python3-ptyprocess python3-renderpm python3-reportlab
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-secretstorage python3-simplejson python3-six
  python3-software-properties python3-systemd python3-talloc python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-wadllib python3-xcffib python3-xkit
  python3-yaml python3.8 ristretto samba-libs sane-utils sgt-launcher sgt-puzzles simple-scan software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  spice-vdagent sqlite3 sublime-text system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman thunderbird transmission-gtk tumbler ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unattended-upgrades update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common vim whoopsie
  wine-stable-amd64 wine64 xarchiver xdg-user-dirs-gtk xfburn xfce4 xfce4-appfinder xfce4-appmenu-plugin xfce4-battery-plugin xfce4-clipman
  xfce4-clipman-plugin xfce4-cpufreq-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-diskperf-plugin xfce4-equake-plugin
  xfce4-eyes-plugin xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-genmon-plugin xfce4-goodies xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-mount-plugin
  xfce4-mpc-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-panel-dev xfce4-panel-profiles xfce4-places-plugin
  xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-plugins xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin xfce4-screensaver xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-sensors-plugin xfce4-session
  xfce4-settings xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-sntray-plugin xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal
  xfce4-time-out-plugin xfce4-timer-plugin xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-wavelan-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin
  xfdesktop4 xfpanel-switch xfwm4 xiccd xorg xserver-xorg xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-core xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop
  xubuntu-live-settings yelp zenity

Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  libsqlite3-0:i386

0 actualizados, 1 nuevos se instalarán, 417 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 626 kB de archivos.
Se liberarán 2.902 MB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] n

Anulado.

**name@name-desktop:~/Descargas$ sudo apt update**

Des:1 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17,1 kB]
Obj:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                
Obj:3 http://download.zerotier.com/debian/buster buster InRelease                                                                                    
Obj:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                      
Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                                                                             
Obj:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                      
Obj:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                                                                               
Obj:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
Obj:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                       
Des:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                          
Obj:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                             
Obj:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                        
Des:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease [115 kB]                                                                            
Obj:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                     
Obj:16 https://qgis.org/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                      
Obj:17 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_15.x groovy InRelease                                                                                         
Obj:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                    
Des:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 kB]          
Obj:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Descargados 353 kB en 2s (165 kB/s)       
                   
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Todos los paquetes están actualizados.
```

If you need more information just ask me.

Edit:
apt-cache policy wine64 wine32  libsqlite3-0:i386 libsqlite3-0:amd64 command.

```
name@name-desktop:~$ apt-cache policy wine64 wine32  libsqlite3-0:i386 libsqlite3-0:amd64
wine64:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  5.0.3-3
  Tabla de versión:
     5.0.3-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages
wine32:i386:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  5.0.3-3
  Tabla de versión:
     5.0.3-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe i386 Packages
libsqlite3-0:i386:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  3.34.1-3
  Tabla de versión:
     3.34.1-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
libsqlite3-0:
  Instalados: 3.35.0-1-17377~202104021520~202104041958~ubuntu21.04.1
  Candidato:  3.35.0-1-17377~202104021520~202104041958~ubuntu21.04.1
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 3.35.0-1-17377~202104021520~202104041958~ubuntu21.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.34.1-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You must fix `Esto puede significar que usted pidió una situación imposible` before anything else. Do you understand why you are getting that message?

Comment: Not really, I try to search but I do not find something that was useful.

Comment: You broke your system by specifically telling apt to install some package that conflicts with the rest of your system. Usually some non-Ubuntu package from some non-Ubuntu source. Sometimes other possibilities. You must figure out which package it is and then uninstall it. If you cannot figure it out, you will eventually wind up reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Your output says that your entire desktop environment is eligible for autoremoval. You should fix that, too.

Comment: Okey, I understand do you know any command or program that will help me to find that non-Ubuntu program? And how I make that my entire desktop enviroment is not elegible for autoremove, there is a program or a file that should I change?

Comment: Uh-oh: The level of your skill suggested by your questions, combined with the kinds of problems your have created, seems troubling to me. I don't think you can fix these problems without much more extensive tutoring than AskUbuntu is intended to provide. Perhaps another volunteer will take up that task. I'm going to recommend that you back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu. There are many, many examples of both of these problems among the questions on AskUbuntu if you want to learn more about how your system works and how can indeed fox it yourself.

Comment: Okey, I understand your opinion

Comment: please can you add `apt-cache policy wine64 wine32  libsqlite3-0:i386 libsqlite3-0:amd64` .

Comment: Okey, I did. Is it on the Edit part

Comment: `apt -s install --reinstall libsqlite3-0= 3.34.1-3` Is only a simulation. the package versions from   libsqlite3-0 (it is from a ppa on your system)  and  libsqlite3-0:i386 are different. Fix this first and try again.

Comment: Thx, the problem was that. Thanks